# No HDMI output when the monitor is turned off at boot (no signal)

Tags: hdmi, raspbian-buster

I am using Magic Mirror together with my Raspberry Pi 3B+ (Buster) and an old laptop monitor. The website is displayed using kiosk mode with chromium. When my RPi normally starts, the monitor is turned off. That's why I've added `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` to /boot/config.txt. But this doesn't work, somehow the hdmi output is off and the monitor says no signal detected. I've also set several settings to match my monitor settings:

/boot/config.txt

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=800

# use edid_file in boot folder
#hdmi_edid_file=1

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=28

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=9

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
# Next line commented out, cuz dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d is now in use
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
# Magic Mirror added
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
avoid_warnings=1
```

But this is not working, if I turn the monitor on after boot, it says no signal detected.

I even tried a workaround by turning it after boot on with the command:

```
pi@himbipi:~ $ sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p
Powering on HDMI with preferred settings
[E] Failed to power on HDMI with preferred settings
```

But without success. It's strange, that the poweroff doesn't show any error and the monitor is staying on though:

```
pi@himbipi:~ $ sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o
Powering off HDMI
```

Maybe the settings in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` are influencing the behaviour?

```
pi@himbipi:/boot $ cat /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
# Bildschirmschoner deaktivieren
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s noblank
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
# Bildschirm drehen
@xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate right
# Mauszeiger ausblenden
@unclutter -display :0 -idle 3 -root -noevents
# lädt Chromium im Vollbild bei einem Neustart
@chromium-browser --no-default-browser-check --check-for-update-interval=604800 --disable-pinch --incognito --kiosk http://localhost:80
```

At this point I don't have a clue, can anyone help me please? :)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is because your screen does not support the mode you're trying to set (`hdmi_group=2, hdmi_mode=28` seems to be 288p with pixel quadrupling).

Start the Pi with the screen switched on, note the mode it is set to (using `tvservice` or otherwise), and set that mode in your `config.txt`.